# What was Little Nobody trying to convey to Dominic before he was interrupted by Dante?

Tags: plot-explanation, fast-x

In the streets of Rome, Dom stopped the rolling bomb that had
fallen out of the truck Dante had placed it in, with his car.
He told Little Nobody that it was his turn to take action:

> Dom: Little Nobody, you're up.
>
> Little Nobody : **Moving to dis...**

Suddenly, Little Nobody came across Dante, who was driving alongside
him, and planted a bomb on his car:

> Dante: Peekaboo!

What was Little Nobody trying to convey to Dominic before he was interrupted by Dante?

Comment: A very quick look at the script shows that Little Nobody is trying to *dis*arm a bomb.  Perhaps that?  This questions shows very little thought or prior research.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is showing very little attempt at basic comprehension of the movie